# iterator over references of std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a class that has `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` and I want to crate an iterator over the reference of pointers that `std::unique_ptr` holds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class Pointer
{
public:
    Pointer() {}
    ~Pointer() {}

    void printSomething()
    {
        std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Keeper
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pointer>> vector_type;

    Keeper() {}
    virtual ~Keeper() {}

    void push_back(vector_type::value_type pointer)
    {
        data.push_back(pointer);
    }

    vector_type::const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return data.begin();
    }

    vector_type::const_iterator end() const
    {
        return data.end();
    }
private:
    vector_type data;
};

int main()
{
    Keeper keeper;
    keeper.push_back(std::make_unique<Pointer>());

    std::for_each(keeper.begin(), keeper.end(), [] (auto pointer) {
        pointer.printSomething();
    });
}
```

I got a cascade of errors that I cannot put here...

How to provide an interface to interact over the references of `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: What's wrong with the normal vector iterator?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `vector` has a `typedef` for its iterator type.

Comment: I guess it's better to interchange the declarations and use a `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Pointer> >` instead.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because I _think_ what you're asking is "how do I get an iterator that returns a `Pointer` when dereferenced, instead of a `unique_ptr<Pointer>`?" If that's not what you're asking please clarify the question and re-open it.

Comment: [fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c18de9dd35c86cf4)

Comment: Why not just say `pointer->printSomething()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes of your code are necessary.

```
#include<type_traits>

class Keeper
{
//...
public:
    void push_back(value_type&& pointer)
    {
        data.push_back(std::move(pointer));                                  //(1)
    }
//...    
};

int main()
{
    // ...

    std::for_each(keeper.begin(), keeper.end(), [] (auto const& pointer) {   //(2)
        pointer->printSomething();                                           //(3)
    });
}
```

**(1)** Pass the `unique_ptr` by rvalue reference and `move` it into the vector. This is necessary as you cannot copy a `unique_ptr`, but only apply moves. Alternatively and nicer, you could use `emplace_back` and simply pass the constructor arguments

```
template<typename ... Args>
void emplace_back(Args&& ... args)
{
    data.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
}
```

Note that the previous call is equivalent to the following, as the compiler makes an implicit conversion:

```
data.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Pointer>(std::forward<Args>(args) ...));
```

**(2)** Pass the elements of the vector, by reference. Again, this is necessary as you cannot pass them by value which means a copy.

**(3)** As it is a pointer, you have to dereference the passed element via `->`.

Comment: I've just seen that Brian Chen already provided almost the samein his comment to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution for this problem is already implemented in Boost.Iterator. And it's sexy:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
// [..]

using iterator = boost::indirect_iterator<decltype(vec)::iterator>;
iterator iter = vec.begin(),
         end = vec.end();
```

[`indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html) can be found in `<boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>`.
Can be used as follows:

```
while (iter != end)
    std::cout << *iter++ << ", ";
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17d662c3a5511c90).